# CFBridgingRelease of a CFArray containing CFString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Suppose I have a CFArray containing CFString's:

```
CFStringRef strs[3];

CFArrayRef anArray;

strs[0] = CFSTR("String One");
strs[1] = CFSTR("String Two");
strs[2] = CFSTR("String Three");

anArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)strs, 3, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
```

If I use CFBridgingRelease to cast the CFArrayRef into an NSArray * (and in the process transfer the ownership of the array object to ARC), then does each element of the original array also get a CFBridgingRelease call automatically? It seems like, once I do:

```
NSArray * arrayInArc = CFBridgingRelease(anArray);
```

I can treat the elements of the NSArray as NSString's without having explicitly called CFBridgingRelease on each of the original CFStringRef:

```
NSString * a0 = arrayInArc[0];
```

Is there any documentation saying that when you transfer of the ownership of a collection (e.g., CFArray) to ARC, the ownership of its elements are also transferred?

Thanks,

Comment: You do not need to cast to/from `void *`. ---- Apart from that: the array owns its elements. It retains and releases them whenever necessary. You don't have to worry about that. Whether or not the elements are retained, released, inside the array or not in the array, as long as **you** own a reference to them, you can use them, and you have to release them. (Well, you don't have to release them in this case, since you have constant strings, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the CFBridingRelease doesn't change the type of the array.. CFArrayRef <> NSArray* is the same even before, It just tells the compiler to manage retain/release calls for you

how the array releases its contents is not affected by it.
YOU don't have references to the content, the array does! And the CFArrayRef/NSArray* manages the retain/release calls with/without arc.

---

**the basic idea: only care about releasing stuff YOU own. (In this case the array itself)**